# Understanding rig joint angle definitions in Blender

Tags: animation

I am trying to transfer some mocap data from one skeleton to another one. However, the skeletons have different rest poses (one has T-pose, and the other some other one), so I am trying to convert the euler angles from being relative to one rest pose to another. I have the relative transform between the second skeleton and a T-pose in Unity. The issue is that Unity uses a different angle convention to Blender/BVH, and I really cannot figure it out.

Trying to debug this, I've isolated one point of confusion, which is what I'm mainly asking about here. You can see [in this video](https://streamable.com/80nyoj) that for all joints up to the spine3, changing the X Euler angle, rotates arond X, but after the collar joints, changing the X Euler angle, it rotates around some other axis (even though all of its parents have near 0 rotation). I don't understand why this would be. Anyone could explain this?
Thanks!